# Save API JSON Response directly to Azure Blob Storage json file

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-http-trigger

I am calling to a 3rd party API directly in an Azure HTTP Function. I would like to save the json response to a file inside Azure Blob Storage container. The below code I built (based on [microsoft documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob#uploading-a-blob)) hangs when I try debugging the Azure Function. When hitting the Azure Function URL endpoint, the above process hangs and never finishes the tasks. Is my code missing something?

```
import os
import logging
import requests
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,BlobClient
import json

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    connection_string = os.getenv([Azure Blob Storage Connection String])
    file_name = 'SurveySchema.json'
    blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string, container_name=[container name], blob_name=[name of json file])
    request = requests.get('[The API endpoint that returns json response body]')
    try:
        logging.info(request.text)
        blob.set(str(request.text))
    except ValueError as err:
        logging.info("Error getting data from endpoint, %s", err)

    return func.HttpResponse('Request processed successfully.', status_code=200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an easy fix! I had to use "upload_blob" method from Blob Client library

```
import os
import logging
import requests
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,BlobClient
import json

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    connection_string = os.getenv([Azure Blob Storage Connection String])
    file_name = 'SurveySchema.json'
    blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string, container_name=[container name], blob_name=[name of json file])
    request = requests.get('[The API endpoint that returns json response body]')
    try:
        logging.info(request.text)
        **blob.upload_blob(str(request.text))**
    except ValueError as err:
        logging.info("Error getting data from endpoint, %s", err)

    return func.HttpResponse('Request processed successfully.', status_code=200)
```